# write() not called when subclassing code.InteractiveInterpreter

Tags: python, console

When subclassing code.InteractiveInterpreter I can't seem to get the write() method to run as I would expect per the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html).

```
import code

class PythonInterpreter(code.InteractiveInterpreter):
    def __init__(self, localVars):
        self.runResult = ''
        print 'init called'
        code.InteractiveInterpreter.__init__(self, localVars)

    def write(self, data):
        print 'write called'
        self.runResult = data

test = 'Hello'
interpreter = PythonInterpreter({'test':test})
interpreter.runcode('print test')
print 'Result:' + interpreter.runResult
```

Expected output:

```
init called
write called
Result: Hello
```

Actual output:

```
init called
Hello   <- shouldn't print
Result:
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The write method is not used by the code passed to runcode at all. You would have to redirect stdout for this to work, e.g. something like:

```
import code

class PythonInterpreter(code.InteractiveInterpreter):
    def __init__(self, localVars):
        self.runResult = ''
        print 'init called'
        code.InteractiveInterpreter.__init__(self, localVars)

    def write(self, data):
        # since sys.stdout is probably redirected,
        # we can't use print
        sys.__stdout__.write('write called\n')
        self.runResult = data

    def runcode(cd):
        # redirecting stdout to our method write before calling code cd
        sys.stdout = self
        code.InteractiveInterpreter.runcode(self,cd)
        # redirecting back to normal stdout
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```